# Calculating the following curveintegral with Greens formula.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, curves

Suppose i want to calculate the work done by the vector field

$$ F(x,y) =\left(-\frac{y}{x^2 + y^2},
 \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2 }\right) $$

when a particle is moving along the ellipse $$ x^2 + \frac{y^2}{4} = 1  $$ from the point (1,0) to (0,-2).

The way i've gone to solve the problem is to enclose the curve by connecting it with the unit circle from (1,0) to (0,-1) and with the line from (0,-1) to (0,-2).

By doing this i've managed to enclose the curve in a way that it is positive orientated. Also since the zone enclosed by the curve doesn't include (0,0) i should be able to use Greens formula.

I get that:

$$ \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = 0 $$

so $$  \int\!\!\int_D  \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\,dxdy = 0 $$

I then calculate the curve integral from the curves i added to enclose the zone D, and subtract it to arrive to the answer:

$$ W=\int_{\gamma}Pdx+Qdy = \frac{\pi}{2} $$. But the answer should be $$ \frac{3\pi}{2} $$, so im clearly doing something wrong, but i have no idea what.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Most likely your parametrization is incorrect or in the wrong direction, post those details.

Comment: For the unit circle from (1,0) to (0,-1) I've used the parametrization x = cos t and y = sin t, and letting t go from  0 to $$ -\frac{\pi}{2} $$. For the line from (0,-1) to (0,-2) i've used the parametrization x = 0, and y = -1-t, and letting t go from 0 to 1.

Comment: yes, that is incorrect as I suspected. You were supposed to go the long way around the circle.

Comment: @hamam you have not understood the shape correctly. It is this ellipse, the unit circle, plus a line segment on the $y$ axis connecting the two. It looks like a goat horn.

Comment: @Fosofof the paramter $ t $ should go from 0 to 3pi/2.

Comment: Yes I agree with the comments from @hamam_Abdallah . May be you were told positive orientation which you have missed in the question. In that case you are going from $0$ to $\frac{3\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Maybe i have been working for too long on the problem so i can't see it clearly, but why can't the parameter t go from 0 to -pi/2? Also if i want the parameter t to go from 0 to 3pi/2 i can't use x = cos t and y = sin t, since that would give me points outside of the curve, right? Sorry if I'm asking stupid questions.

Comment: @MathLover That is correct. In the textbook it literally says positive orientation from (1,0) to (0,-2), but if I'm going from (1,0) to (0,-2), i have to go in a negative orientation, right? So the textbook have to be wrong about the positive orientation part?

Comment: No you should add it to the question. If it is positive orientation then what you have done is not correct.

Comment: You move on the circle from $0$ to $3\pi/2$ and then the line.

Comment: Draw a diagram of both and you can see it.

Comment: @MathLover I just realized that it is possible to go in a positive orientation from (1,0) to (0,-2) by going the long way around. By doing this i get 3 quarters of the ellips and not one quarter only. My bad, no idea how i missed that for so long. Sorry for bothering you all.